# Mule ESB - how to check sftp:outbound-endpoint connection got successfully or not

Tags: mule, sftp, mule-component

Can anybody tell me how to verify that whether sftp:outbound-endpoint connection got successfully or not at mule level itself(in mule-config.xml).

Is there any parameter/attribute for sftp outbound-endpoint which tells connection got successfully or not?

I am creating a file and deploying that file to ftp sever using sftp outbound-endpoint and after deploying to sftp server doing some transforms using transformer-refs.

Currently what happening is my connection is getting failed with sftp but transformer class is executing successfully..

So i want to verify at mule level itself whether sftp connection got successfully or not.

Comment: Please provide the application log output that shows the connection error. Regards, Marcos.